# How do you obtain official brand logos for design prototypes?

Tags: copyright

I need to use company logos as a part of my designs. These companies are institutions that are stakeholders for my client. Some sites have SVGs you can grab from the website but how does one go about getting those that are not available on the site in a useable format like a PNG or SVG?

Should I ask my client to ask these companies for design assets? Does my client need permission for these logos as well?

Comment: I am not sure if this question is allowed on this site, so I won't post an answer, but... yes, you should seek permission and yes you should ask the companies that own the branding to provide you with the files you need - this should be something they can easily do. Note: taking images from a website would be quite a bad choice, as they are likely to have been optimised for web and may not be good enough quality for all your design needs. (unless they provide branding packages for download that have the original source files).

Answer (score 1):

I have found that PDF files of brochures or other *professionally* designed for-print assets for a company often have high-quality logos which can be extracted.

If not extractable, but still high quality, then zoom in so it fills the screen and then take a screen capture. 1920px wide is about 6.4 inches @ 300ppi. (works better with white backgrounds, but by using greyscale and levels/contrast adjustments, one can often get a decent 1-color facsimile)

"Yes" you need permission in some form from the logo owners. If you are designing a mockup, you might hedge by overlaying "FPO" (for position only) on top of 3rd-party assets.

Answer (score 0):

There are web site databases of logos:

[BrandsOfTheWorld.com](https://www.brandsoftheworld.com/)

[SeekLogo.com](https://seeklogo.com/)

I'm sure there's more.

Typically one **does** ask the client for logos if they are necessary.